# captcha image is display

Tags: php, captcha

I have code which display captcha in my local machine. But when I put that code in server then captcha image not working. Please any body solve my problem. My local machine is ubuntu 12.04, and server machine is ubuntu 14.04. Below is my code.

**demo.php**

```
<?php session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    // code for check server side validation
    if(empty($_SESSION['captcha_code'] ) || strcasecmp($_SESSION['captcha_code'], $_POST['captcha_code']) != 0){  
        $msg="<span style='color:red'>The Validation code does not match!</span>";// Captcha verification is incorrect.     
    }else{// Captcha verification is Correct. Final Code Execute here!      
        $msg="<span style='color:green'>The Validation code has been matched.</span>";      
    }
}   
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Secure Professional Captcha.</title>
<link href="./css/stylecaptcha.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type='text/javascript'>
function refreshCaptcha(){
    var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
    img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<br>

<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" >
  <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="table">
    <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top"> Validation code:</td>
      <td><img src="captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" id='captchaimg'><br>
        <label for='message'>Enter the code above here :</label>
        <br>
        <input id="captcha_code" name="captcha_code" type="text">
        <br>
        Cannot read the image? click <a href='javascript: refreshCaptcha();'>here</a> to refresh.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="return validate();" value="Submit" class="button1"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**captcha.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("./phptextClass.php");  

    /*create class object*/
    $phptextObj = new phptextClass();   
    /*phptext function to genrate image with text*/
    $phptextObj->phpcaptcha('#162453','#fff',120,40,10,25); 
 ?>
```

**phptextClass.php**

```
<?php
/*phptext class, version 1.0
created by www.w3schools.in (Gautam kumar)
April 26, 2014
*/
class phptextClass
{   
    public function phptext($text,$textColor,$backgroundColor='',$fontSize,$imgWidth,$imgHeight,$dir,$fileName)
    {
        /* settings */
        $font = './calibri.ttf';/*define font*/
        $textColor=$this->hexToRGB($textColor); 

        $im = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth, $imgHeight);  
        $textColor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textColor['r'],$textColor['g'],$textColor['b']);  

        if($backgroundColor==''){/*select random color*/
            $colorCode=array('#56aad8', '#61c4a8', '#d3ab92');
            $backgroundColor = $this->hexToRGB($colorCode[rand(0, count($colorCode)-1)]);
            $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($im, $backgroundColor['r'],$backgroundColor['g'],$backgroundColor['b']);
        }else{/*select background color as provided*/
            $backgroundColor = $this->hexToRGB($backgroundColor);
            $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($im, $backgroundColor['r'],$backgroundColor['g'],$backgroundColor['b']);
        }

        imagefill($im,0,0,$backgroundColor);    
        list($x, $y) = $this->ImageTTFCenter($im, $text, $font, $fontSize); 
        imagettftext($im, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $textColor, $font, $text);
        if(imagejpeg($im,$dir.$fileName,90)){/*save image as JPG*/
            return json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE,'image'=>$dir.$fileName));
        imagedestroy($im);  
        }
    }   

    public function phpcaptcha($textColor,$backgroundColor,$imgWidth,$imgHeight,$noiceLines=0,$noiceDots=0,$noiceColor='#000000')
    {   
        /* Settings */
        $text=$this->random();
        $font = './font/monofont.ttf';/* font */
        $textColor=$this->hexToRGB($textColor); 
        $fontSize = $imgHeight * 0.75;

        $im = imagecreatetruecolor($imgWidth, $imgHeight);  
        $textColor = imagecolorallocate($im, $textColor['r'],$textColor['g'],$textColor['b']);          

        $backgroundColor = $this->hexToRGB($backgroundColor);
        $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($im, $backgroundColor['r'],$backgroundColor['g'],$backgroundColor['b']);

        /* generating lines randomly in background of image */
        if($noiceLines>0){
        $noiceColor=$this->hexToRGB($noiceColor);   
        $noiceColor = imagecolorallocate($im, $noiceColor['r'],$noiceColor['g'],$noiceColor['b']);
        for( $i=0; $i<$noiceLines; $i++ ) {             
            imageline($im, mt_rand(0,$imgWidth), mt_rand(0,$imgHeight),
            mt_rand(0,$imgWidth), mt_rand(0,$imgHeight), $noiceColor);
        }}              

        if($noiceDots>0){/* generating the dots randomly in background */
        for( $i=0; $i<$noiceDots; $i++ ) {
            imagefilledellipse($im, mt_rand(0,$imgWidth),
            mt_rand(0,$imgHeight), 3, 3, $textColor);
        }}      

        imagefill($im,0,0,$backgroundColor);    
        list($x, $y) = $this->ImageTTFCenter($im, $text, $font, $fontSize); 
        imagettftext($im, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $textColor, $font, $text);      

        imagejpeg($im,NULL,90);/* Showing image */
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');/* defining the image type to be shown in browser widow */
        imagedestroy($im);/* Destroying image instance */
        if(isset($_SESSION)){
            $_SESSION['captcha_code'] = $text;/* set random text in session for captcha validation*/
        }
    }

    /*for random string*/
    protected function random($characters=6,$letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz'){
        $str='';
        for ($i=0; $i<$characters; $i++) { 
            $str .= substr($letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($letters)-1), 1);
        }
        return $str;
    }   

    /*function to convert hex value to rgb array*/
    protected function hexToRGB($colour)
    {
            if ( $colour[0] == '#' ) {
                    $colour = substr( $colour, 1 );
            }
            if ( strlen( $colour ) == 6 ) {
                    list( $r, $g, $b ) = array( $colour[0] . $colour[1], $colour[2] . $colour[3], $colour[4] . $colour[5] );
            } elseif ( strlen( $colour ) == 3 ) {
                    list( $r, $g, $b ) = array( $colour[0] . $colour[0], $colour[1] . $colour[1], $colour[2] . $colour[2] );
            } else {
                    return false;
            }
            $r = hexdec( $r );
            $g = hexdec( $g );
            $b = hexdec( $b );
            return array( 'r' => $r, 'g' => $g, 'b' => $b );
    }       

    /*function to get center position on image*/
    protected function ImageTTFCenter($image, $text, $font, $size, $angle = 8) 
    {
        $xi = imagesx($image);
        $yi = imagesy($image);
        $box = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);
        $xr = abs(max($box[2], $box[4]));
        $yr = abs(max($box[5], $box[7]));
        $x = intval(($xi - $xr) / 2);
        $y = intval(($yi + $yr) / 2);
        return array($x, $y);   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think the problem is related to font. Are you sure './font/monofont.ttf' is available and has access permission to apache/nginx?

Comment: no. I found the solution. It is because of php5_gd not installed on my server.